# Regex Identifier for closest elements

Tags: xml, regex, openxml, openxml-sdk

Im trying to construct a Regex Identifier for the following...

```
<w:p>
    Some Other XML
        <w:p someatribute="something">
        HERE
        </w:p>
    Some Other XML
</w:p>
```

The Identifier needs to select just the following part...

```
        <w:p someatribute="something">
        HERE
        </w:p>
```

And leave everything else in palce.

My current attempt... `<w:p(.*?)Test(.*?):p>`

Is selecting everything from the above sample. Can regex help me here to identify just the closest match and any text in between?

Many thanks!

TR

Comment: Why would you do this with regex as opposed to standard DOM traversal techniques?

Comment: Well, if you know that there is only text in between, then `<w:p[^>]*?>([^<>]*?)Test([^<>]*?)<\/w:p>` might do - but [in general, **NO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572).

Comment: Okay thanks chaps perhaps ill open up another question on how to revise what i am doing then. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(<w:p[^>]+>(?:(?!<\/wp>).)+?<\/w:p>)
```

Try this.Set flags `s`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/40

Comment: Worked Great Thanks, atleast it did what i requested. Didn't solve my issue but helped me narrow it down thanks a bunch.

Turns out you cant delete a paragraph from using XML SDK if it leaves a parent of Type TableCell empty. I guess TableCells need atleast one paragraph in them. Have gone back to using standard OpenXML SDK doing a compare on the types of the parents.